# Reflection principle and compactness theorem in ZFC

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I can't see where I'm wrong in the following reasoning.

For the [Reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle), for every finite set $\Gamma$ of sentences of **ZFC** we can proof that
$$
ZFC\vdash\exists M(M\models\Gamma).
$$
So, this means that **ZFC** *finitely consistent*. Now by [Compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem), we can conclude that
$$
ZFC\vdash\exists M(M\models ZFC).
$$
I know that, by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, this is imposible.

Then, where is my mistake?

Comment: Reflection says more than that, actually. Everything that is true in the universe, is true in a closed and unbounded class of points which reflect this. In particular, every finite subtheory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that the reflection theorem is really a metatheorem - it is a scheme of theorems which says

> For every finite $\Gamma \subseteq \text{ZFC}$, we have $\text{ZFC} \vdash \text{Con}(\Gamma)$.

The reflection theorem does **not** say

> $ \text{ZFC} \vdash \text{For every finite } \Gamma \subseteq \text{ZFC}, \text{Con}(\Gamma)$.

If ZFC proved the latter, then because of compactness, as you wrote, ZFC would prove its own consistency. But the former does not contradict compactness, because the quantifier over finite subtheories is on the left side of the turnstyle.

The Wikipedia article is currently written in a confusing way, but one that is somewhat common in the way that many people write about these principles in set theory.

Also see: [Montague's Reflection Principle and Compactness Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18787/montagues-reflection-principle-and-compactness-theorem) on MathOverflow